# Array of file names: how to move 2 certain files (if present) to the front?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

In a [build.rake](https://github.com/wooga/Pocket-Island/blob/master/tasks/build.rake) file I have an array holding names of JavaScript files:

```
JS_FROM_INDEX=`./bin/extract_files -e js index.html`.split
```

It holds these files:

```
js/config.js
js/vendor/dollar.js
js/vendor/ejs.min.js
js/utils.js
......
js/Viewport.js
```

Then there is a rule which (it is my guess as I'm completely ignorant to ruby yet) tells how to make the **build/app.js** file: namely take the **js/config.js** file first and then append all other files from the above array to it:

```
file DEST + '/app.js' => [DEST]+JS_FROM_INDEX.dup << 'index.html' << DEST do |t|
  sh "cat js/config.js > #{t.name}"
  sh "cat #{JS_FROM_INDEX.reject{|f| f =~ /\/config\.js/ }.join(" ")} | bin/yuicompressor --type js >> #{t.name}"
end
```

It works ok, but now I've found out, that **js/utils.js** should be at the very beginning, even before the **js/config.js**.

So my questions is:

Is there a nice way to sort the **JS_FROM_INDEX** array, so that **js/utils.js** and **js/config.js** are moved to its first positions? Can this be done as a oneliner (i.e. some code appended to the **.split** call above)?

**UPDATE:**

Meager has suggested (thank you!) the code:

```
scripts.unshift("js/config.js") if scripts.delete("js/config.js");
scripts.unshift("js/utils.js") if scripts.delete("js/utils.js");
```

To integrate that into the Rakefile I think I need to introduce 2 more variables:

```
JS_FROM_INDEX=`./bin/extract_files -e js index.html`.split
JS_SORTED_1=......use JS_FROM_INDEX somehow....
JS_SORTED_2=......use JS_FROM_SORTED_1 somehow....

file DEST + '/app.js' => [DEST]+JS_SORTED_2.dup << 'index.html' << DEST do |t|
  sh "cat #{JS_FROM_INDEX.reject{|f| f =~ /\/config\.js/ }.join(" ")} | bin/yuicompressor --type js >> #{t.name}"
end
```

Any ideas please on how to *connect the dots* above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the item from the array and then (if it was found during the delete) push it onto the front of the array:

```
scripts = %w(js/config.js
            js/vendor/dollar.js
            js/vendor/ejs.min.js
            js/utils.js)

# Move config.js first
scripts.unshift("js/config.js") if scripts.delete("js/config.js");

# Move utils.js second to ensure it is always before config.js
scripts.unshift("js/utils.js") if scripts.delete("js/utils.js");
```

Here, [`delete`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete) returns `nil` if the item to delete wasn't found, so the item is never [`unshift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-unshift)ed back onto the front.

You could easily make this more generic with by iterating over a list:

```
items_to_sort_to_front.each { |item| scripts.unshift(item) if scripts.delete(item) }
```

Just remember to sort `items_to_sort_to_front` *backwards*, as the last item in the list will be the last one moved to the front of `scripts`.

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense. I just wonder how to add this to the Rakefile, since I'm coming from perl/Makefiles background... Can it be done as a oneliner and appended to the `.split` call?